# division by 2 in Binary Signed digit (Redundant Binary representation)

Tags: binary, hardware, vhdl

How can I do division by 2 in Binary Signed digit (Redundant Binary representation) ? Shifting won't work right ?

Comment: What's your target architecture?  ASIC? FPGA?  Can you use software?
You should tell us more about your *specific* RBR as well.

Answer (score 0):

A redundant binary representation is just an expression of the form:

```
\sum_{i=0}^n d_i 2^n
```

where the `d_i`'s are drawn from a larger set than just `{0,1}`.

Dividing by two or shifting right takes that to

```
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d_{i+1} 2^n + f(d_0)
```

The trick comes in how to deal with adjusting for the redundant representation for `d_0`.

If your RBR has digits the form `{0,1,2}` and has a 2 for the least significant digit you will then have to add `1` to the result to compensate, so `f(0) = 0`, `f(1) = 0`, `f(2) = 1` should work.

- `4 = 12_base2`, so `12_base2 >> 1` = `1 + f(2)` = `1 + 1` = `2_base2` = `2` as expected.
- `6 = 102_base2`, so `102_base2 >> 1` = `10_base2 + f(2)` = `11_base2` = `3`

You can get something similar for signed redundant binary representations (i.e. with `d_i` in `{-1,0,1}`) by setting `f(-1) = -1`.

- `1 = 1(-1)_base2`, so `1(-1)_base2 >> 1` = `1 + f(-1)` = `1 - 1` = `0`

So ultimately the naive approach of just shifting does work, you just need a fudge factor to account for any redundant encoding of the shifted digits.

If your chosen RBR includes more options, you'll need to adjust the fudge factor accordingly.